# Ubuntu 22.04 does not connect to any Internet address

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, dns

I have an Ubuntu server 22.04 that has been set up recently. It worked a couple days and I turned the first few knobs until one day, I was not able to connect to the Internet anymore. It started when loggin onto the server and attempting to update / upgrade.

I stare at a 0% [working] for quiet some time, followed by:

```
Ign:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
and finally a bunch of errors.
```

ping google.com

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ping 8.8.8.8

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 18433ms
```

ip link show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
 mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 

2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP
 mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 08:60:6e:6a:38:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:60:6e:6a:38:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 37.187.79.93/24 metric 100 brd 37.187.79.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0
       valid_lft 85897sec preferred_lft 85897sec
    inet6 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::1/56 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a60:6eff:fe6a:382a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r

```
default via 37.187.79.254 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp src 37.187.79.93 metric 100
37.187.79.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 37.187.79.93 metric 100
37.187.79.254 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 37.187.79.93 metric 100
213.186.33.99 via 37.187.79.254 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp src 37.187.79.93 metric 100
```

traceroute 1.1.1.1

```
Command 'traceroute' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install inetutils-traceroute  # version 2:2.2-2ubuntu0.1, or
sudo apt install traceroute            # version 1:2.1.0-2
```

tracepath - 1.1.1.1

```
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  37.187.79.253                                         0.555ms
 1:  37.187.79.253                                         0.463ms
 2:  10.17.135.40                                          0.514ms
 3:  10.73.0.232                                           0.352ms
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
            - 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::1/56
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 08:60:6e:6a:38:2a
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2001:41d0:3:163::1
            routes:
            -   to: default
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f00::/58
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f80::/58
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f60::/59
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fc0::/59
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f40::/60
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fe0::/60
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f50::/61
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2ff0::/61
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f58::/62
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2ff8::/62
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5e::/63
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2ffc::/63
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5c::/64
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2ffe::/64
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:8000::/65
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:8000::/65
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:4000::/66
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:4000::/66
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:2000::/67
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:2000::/67
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:1000::/68
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:1000::/68
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:800::/69
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:800::/69
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:400::/70
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:400::/70
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:200::/71
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:200::/71
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:100::/72
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:100::/72
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:80::/73
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff::/73
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:40::/74
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:80::/74
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:20::/75
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:c0::/75
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:10::/76
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:e0::/76
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:8::/77
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:f0::/77
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:4::/78
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:f8::/78
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:2::/79
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:fc::/79
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:1::/80
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:fe::/80
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:8000::/81
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:8000::/81
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:4000::/82
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:4000::/82
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:2000::/83
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:2000::/83
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:1000::/84
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:1000::/84
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:800::/85
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:800::/85
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:400::/86
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:400::/86
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:200::/87
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:200::/87
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:100::/88
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:100::/88
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:80::/89
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff::/89
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:40::/90
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:80::/90
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:20::/91
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:c0::/91
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:10::/92
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:e0::/92
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:8::/93
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:f0::/93
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:4::/94
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:f8::/94
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:2::/95
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:fc::/95
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d:0:1::/96
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:fe::/96
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::8000:0/97
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:8000:0/97
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::4000:0/98
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:4000:0/98
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::2000:0/99
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:2000:0/99
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::1000:0/100
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:1000:0/100
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::800:0/101
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:800:0/101
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::400:0/102
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:400:0/102
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::200:0/103
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:200:0/103
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::100:0/104
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:100:0/104
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::80:0/105
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff::/105
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::40:0/106
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:80:0/106
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::20:0/107
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:c0:0/107
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::10:0/108
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:e0:0/108
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::8:0/109
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:f0:0/109
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::4:0/110
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:f8:0/110
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::2:0/111
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:fc:0/111
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::1:0/112
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:fe:0/112
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::8000/113
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:8000/113
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::4000/114
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:4000/114
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::2000/115
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:2000/115
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::1000/116
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:1000/116
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::800/117
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:800/117
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::400/118
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:400/118
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::200/119
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:200/119
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::100/120
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:100/120
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::80/121
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:0/121
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::40/122
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:80/122
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::20/123
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:c0/123
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::10/124
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:e0/124
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::8/125
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:f0/125
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::4/126
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:f8/126
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::2/127
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:fc/127
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2f5d::/128
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            -   to: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:fe/128
                via: 2001:41d0:a:2fff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            set-name: enp3s0
``
```

Comment: You didn't mention how your "server" is connected to the Internet and about your network topology in general. Are you using DHCP to assign an IP address to your "server"? Please [edit] your question and add the `ip a` command output.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have added the information as you requested.

Comment: OK. `traceroute` command is not installed and I guess you cannot install it, because of problems in Internet connectivity. Then, please use the `tracepath -n 1.1.1.1` command instead.

Comment: You are right. traceroute does not work. tracepath does.

Comment: `tracepath` output is too short. Are you sure there is no more output? I guess you are using a server at ***OVH***. Please, ask them about the network problem.

Comment: I have added the two missing lines 4 and 5. I had removed them since there is no reply. And yes, OVH it is.

Comment: Any more ideas why I encounter this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for having me and the command has been added.

Comment: Can you: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`?